# How can I write a unit test which includes ApexPages.StandardController methods?

Tags: unit-test, dynamic-visualforce, controller-extension, apex, standardcontroller

Currently looking at the [Using Dynamic References with Custom Objects and Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_custom.htm) tutorial.

For reasons I won't speculate on, step 7 included the controller extension code (again) instead of the unit test code, so I took it as a challenge to myself to write the unit tests, after doing a little refactoring of the controller extension itself.

So, now the extension looks like this:

```
public virtual class VF_BookVFCtrlExt 
    {
        @testVisible private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
        @testVisible private Set<String>                  bookFieldnameSet  = new Set<String>();
        @testVisible private List<String>                 availableFieldList;

        public VF_BookVFCtrlExt (ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
        {
            this.standardController = standardController;
            buildBookFieldNameSet(Schema.SObjectType.Book__c.fields.getMap());

            if (!bookFieldnameSet.isEmpty()) { addFieldsToController(bookFieldnameSet, false); }
        }

        @testVisible private void buildBookFieldNameSet(Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldByNameMap)
        {
            for (String fieldName : fieldByNameMap.keySet())
            {
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = fieldByNameMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();

                // Only include accessible fields
                if (field.isAccessible() && field.isCustom()) 
                { 
                    bookFieldnameSet.add(fieldName); 
                }           
            }
        }

        public List<String> getAvailableFieldList()
        {
                addFieldsToController(bookFieldnameSet, true);
                return new List<String>(bookFieldnameSet);
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private virtual void addFieldsToController(Set<String> fieldNameSet, Boolean needsReset)
        {
             if (needsReset) { standardController.reset(); }

             standardController.addFields(new List<String>(fieldNameSet));
        }   

    }
```

And my unit tests look like this:

```
@isTest
public class VF_BookVFCtrlExtTest 
{
    private static final User TEST_RUN_USER = TEST_DummyUserFactory.createDefaultTestRunUser();

    @isTest private static void testAvailableFieldList()
    {
         // GIVEN
         Book__c dummyBook = TEST_DummyBookFactory.create(TEST_DummyInsertModeEnum.REAL);
         VF_BookVFCtrlExt targetVFControllerExtension = createBookVFCtrlExt(dummyBook); 

         // WHEN
         List<String> resultFieldList = null;
         System.runAs(TEST_RUN_USER)
         {
            Test.startTest();
            { 
                resultFieldList = targetVFControllerExtension.getAvailableFieldList(); 
            }
            Test.stopTest();
         }

         // THEN
         List<String> expectedStringList = new List<String>{ 'isbn__c', 'author__c', 'title__c', 'price__c', 'publisher__c' };
         TEST_AssertionHelper.containsSame(expectedStringList, resultFieldList);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @isTest private static void testBuildBookFieldNameSet()
    {
         // GIVEN
         Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> dummyFieldByNameMap = Schema.SObjectType.Book__c.fields.getMap();              

         Book__c dummyBook = TEST_DummyBookFactory.create(TEST_DummyInsertModeEnum.REAL);
         VF_BookVFCtrlExt targetVFControllerExtension = createBookVFCtrlExt(dummyBook); 

         // WHEN
         System.runAs(TEST_RUN_USER)
         {
            Test.startTest();
            {
                targetVFControllerExtension.buildBookFieldNameSet(dummyFieldByNameMap); 
            }
            Test.stopTest(); 
         }

         // THEN
         Set<String> resultBookFieldNameSet = targetVFControllerExtension.bookFieldnameSet;
         List<String> expectedStringList = new List<String>{ 'isbn__c', 'author__c', 'title__c', 'price__c', 'publisher__c' };
         TEST_AssertionHelper.containsSame(expectedStringList, new List<String>(resultBookFieldNameSet));
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static VF_BookVFCtrlExt createBookVFCtrlExt(Book__c dummyBook)
    {
        PageReference pageReference = Page.VF_BookView;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageReference);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', dummyBook.id);
        ApexPages.StandardController dummyStandardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(dummyBook); 
        return new MockBookVFCtrlExt(dummyStandardController);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private class MockBookVFCtrlExt extends VF_BookVFCtrlExt
    {
        public MockBookVFCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) 
        {
            super(standardController);  
        }

        private virtual void addFieldsToController(Set<String> fieldNameSet, Boolean needsReset)
        {
            // Skip these methods for test.
        }
    }
}
```

... which bring me up to 83% coverage.

Uncovered, specifically, is the virtual addFieldsToController() method, which is expected because I mocked this methods.  But I mocked this method because the StandardController methods were causing exceptions like:

- System.SObject Exception: You cannot call addFields after you've already loaded the data.
- System.SObject Exception: You cannot call reset when the data is being passed into the controller by the caller.

I realize, by some standards, 83% coverage is "good enough" for deploy, but as a maximalist, I'd like to provide coverage for this virtual method as well.

Answer (score 3):

On the `addFields` call, I've used the simpler pattern of:

```
public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sc.addFields(new String[] {...});
    }
    ...
}
```

which might squeeze a line or two more of coverage. The core problem is that the platform forces you to add code to allow testing which is not good.

On the subject of coverage, in quite large code bases we target and achieve 90% overall, with some classes at 100% and some at much lower percentages. Our aim is to [test the things that can break](http://junit.org/faq.html#best_2) and aiming much higher doesn't provide a good return for the effort IMHO.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I considered this possibility, but I think mocking allows for cleaner code.   With your solution, we'd still have those lines uncovered.  True 100% is overkill, but it would still be good to know how to test it (if possible) rather than just how to get around it.

Comment: also consider voting for this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YmzmAAC

Comment: 100% Test Coverage is always possible with a cost:  well-written code and / or Transaction Resources (queries, etc.).  Instead of calling `sc.addFields(...)`, query the controller's Record

Comment: Using of Test.isRunningTest is the very last thing you should do in test methods. Just list all required fields on a visualforce page (in hidden area) to let standard controller know about these fields.

Comment: @Yury Agreed your approach is an alternative. Personally I prefer the cohesion of fields used by the controller class being referenced in the controller class. Pushing the fields out into the page is also pretty pointless.

Comment: @KeithC Generally, this is a platform bug and both solutions are just tricky workarounds. In my opinion the purpose of controller and controller extension is only to serve a visualforce page, so declaring of fields on a related vf-page is less terrible than exclude part of code from tests - again, from my point of view.

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution, see:

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/best-practice-related-fields-with-standard-controller-extensions.html

> You don’t have to include a field in `StandardController.addFields()`
>   to get it to be included and avoid that pesky SObject row was
>   retrieved via SOQL without querying error. Simply include it in the
>   visualforce page as an `<apex:outputField>`! Check out this snippet,
>   which resolves the error in question:
>
> ```
> <apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactExt">
> <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Account.BillingCity}" />
> City: {!city}
> </apex:page>
>
> public class ContactExt {
>     public Contact record {get; set;}
>     public String city {
>         get {
>             return record.Account.BillingCity;
>         }
>         private set;
>     }
>
>     public ContactExt(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
>         record = (Contact)sc.getRecord();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> No error! You don’t even need to use the outputField in your page, you
>   can include rendered=”false” — but you do need to have it merge there
>   to have the field pulled into getRecord().

Comment: this solution wouldn't actually work for the askers solutions because his page selects fields dynamically